# Запуск JS на странице из popup.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

Добрый вечер! Пишу расширение для браузера и возникла проблема.
Есть **popup.html** и есть сайт, в главную страницу которого вшивается JS с функцией **injcom()**, так вот, как мне вызвать эту функцию на странице из **popup.html**?

По идее это отдельная html страница, которая никак не принадлежит к сайту и его главной странице, но с другой стороны это часть расширения, JS то в страницу инжектнулся, но вызвать его надо именно из **popup**, например, по клику на кнопку в этом самом **popup.html**.

Думаю, всё более-менее понятно. Заранее огромная благодарность!